# Having a tough time understanding Codeigniter URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is one of those things that just makes me feel like an idjut.

Ok - so I am just starting out with Codeigniter and I just am having a hell of a time getting my head around the URL system.

Here are some relevant config settings up front ( and I'm on MAMP/localhost at the moment )

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/MY_SITE/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

My `.htaccess` file is blank as of now.

So I have a "home" controller, which I hit fine, and it loads my "home_view".  On it I have a registration link ...

```
<p>Not a member yet? <a href="<?php echo site_url('registration'); ?>">Sign Up!</a></p>
```

This renders as the following HTML ...

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/MY_SITE/index.php/registration">Sign Up!</a>
```

Everything fine so far.  But when I click I get a "404 Page Not Found".  I *have* a "registration.php" controller with an index method that loads a "registration_view.php".

This is what is showing in my address bar

```
http://localhost:8888/MY_SITE/index.php/registration
```

Why do I not hit it?

My logs show ..

```
ERROR - 2012-11-13 18:21:12 --> 404 Page Not Found --> registration/index
```

.. WHY DOES FATE HATE ME SO?

Comment: Please post your registration controller.

Comment: By default, Code Igniter will try to call registration on your Home controller. If you add a registration function to your Home controller do you get rid of the 404?  I believe you will need to change your htaccess to get rid of the index.php and load your other controllers

Comment: @stormdrain  .. Well there it was.  Stupid typo, but your comment helped me find it so point for you.

Comment: @emartel Ok.. I knew that by default CI will go to the "default controller" (in this case "home").  But help me understand something.. if I have a "one segment url"  (ie MY_SITE/index.php/contact) .. it is going to look for "contact"  as a method of the default controller first, and then if it doesn't find it there it will look for it as a separate controller, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many possible and most close reason for 404 might be that there's no `index()` function in your controller. Can u post the code??

**EDIT ( Since ans got downvote )** I have to give more explanations.

In this case possible reasons for 404 error can be -

1. Your default controller is set **home** and the url on which your are getting 404 is calling `registration` controller.
2. If there's no registration controller you get 404.
3. If there's no function named as `registration` present in your default home controller.
4. First arguement in URI (after index.php [if htaccess is not used to remove index.php] ) is for controller that will be called. And second argument after index.php is function that will be called from controller mentioned in first argument. In both cases, ie controller and function not present you get 404.
5. If registration is function and it's visibility is set to `private` then you get 404.

Just for note, to make URLs more readable you should include htaccess and add rules to remove index.php.

Comment: This wasn't the problem, but I don't know why you got downvoted, so I gave you an up.

Comment: I didn't down vote him, but your question clearly states that you have an index method in your registration controller...

Comment: @MaximeMorin  Thanks for the clarification.. you just answered a followup question I asked above as well.

THE PROBLEM WAS A TYPO IN MY registration CONTROLLER.

I'll mark you as the correct answer for the completeness of your response.

Comment: @MaximeMorin  I had used .htaccess before, but had removed it to problem solve.  Can I use the same .htaccess file if my site is in a sub-folder?  Ie for "/PROJECTS/THIS_SITE/VERSION_ONE/" .. can I use the same .htaccess as if the site was located at webroot?

Comment: @K.K.Smith thanks, i read your followup question in response to `emartel` comment. What i think in such case is, if there's a function present in your default controller and you pass it as first argument in url, it doesn't look for it in default controller. Instead CI considers it as separate controller.

Comment: @phazorRise  Aw crap.  I was responding to MaximeMorin when I wanted to respond to you.  Thanks for your help.  If you want to answer my question about .htaccess in sub-folder I will bake you a cake.

Comment: @K.K.Smith Ahh, nice question. I haven't tried that before. Good point you've raised. Gotta look into it first. :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19496/discussion-between-phazorrise-and-k-k-smith)